# Use Python and Regex to find text that looks like a sentence

Tags: python

Fill in the code to check if the text passed looks like a standard sentence, meaning that it starts with an uppercase letter, followed by at least some lowercase letters or a space, and ends with a period, question mark, or exclamation point.

```
import re
def check_sentence(text):
  result = re.search(r"____", text)
  return result != None

print(check_sentence("Is this is a sentence?")) # True
print(check_sentence("is this is a sentence?")) # False
print(check_sentence("Hello")) # False
print(check_sentence("1-2-3-GO!")) # False
print(check_sentence("A star is born.")) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def check_sentence(text):
  result = re.search(r"^[A-Z][\sa-z].*[\.\?\!]$", text)
  return result != None

print(check_sentence("Is this is a sentence?")) # True
print(check_sentence("is this is a sentence?")) # False
print(check_sentence("Hello")) # False
print(check_sentence("1-2-3-GO!")) # False
print(check_sentence("A star is born.")) # True
```